# An if and only if condition for a group homomorphism to be surjective.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $\phi: G\to H$ be a group homomorphism. Let $S\subset G$ be a set of generators of $G$, then $\phi$ is an epimorphism iff the set $\phi(S)$ generates $H$.

I wrote the definition of surjective map: $\forall h\in H \exists g\in G:\phi(g)=h$.

But how to proceed from here?
What I thought is that $\phi$ is onto iff $\phi(G)=H$ iff $H=\phi(G)=\phi(\langle S \rangle)=\langle \phi(S) \rangle $

But how to show the last equality?

Comment: Which direction do you find challenging?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  In this sort of question, it is generally easier to prove one direction.  Though in this case, I'd have thought they were roughly comparable in difficulty.

Comment: One should not use "epimorphism" as a synonym for "surjective". Even in the context of dealing with groups, there are settings in which maps can be epimorphisms but not surjective (e.g., the embedding $A_4\hookrightarrow A_5$ is an epimorphism of the variety generated by $A_5$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** The subgroup generated by $S$ has an explicit description given by $\{s_1^{k_1}\cdot\dots\cdot s_n^{k_n}\mid n\in \Bbb N, s_1,…,s_n\in S, k_1,…,k_n\in \Bbb Z\}$. Use this and the defining property of a group homomorphism to obtain the last equality.

Comment: Thanks! I thought it to be easy.